# Why do people use jQuery for basic operations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am a JS programmer and I have been experimenting with jQuery a lot but have run into a couple puzzling aspects.

I feel like people use jQuery for much more than necessary.  I really just want to know why picking jQuery may be better than using just pure JS.

I know it makes sense for webfx like the animate and fades but for things like adding event listeners it seems just as easy to use

```
obj = document.getElementByID(_ID_);
obj.addEventListener("mousedown"...);
```

An example of this is the answer I found on StackOverflow earlier today about performing an action for highlighted text. [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/jquery-get-the-highlighted-text)

In the example linked in the answer at http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html

The guy uses the bind function to the document. Why use bind rather than addEventListener.  Also with jQuery everything needs to be included in the .ready() method how is this better than (or why choose it over)

```
document.addEventListener('load', function () { ... }, false);
```

There are other times I have seen jQuery used that puzzled me, I hope you guys can shine some light on it for me.

Comment: Pure jquery isn't good. It's about performance vs development time. Use jquery only if really needed and performance doesn't matter. I've seen people used $(this).attr('id') instead of this.id. Pure javascript lead in performance but less support for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

People use jQuery because it's simpler, easier, and more powerful, and because it helps them forget about IE.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Otherwise, you need to call `attachEvent` for IE.
   Also, jQuery event handling has simpler syntax, and supports live events.
2. jQuery does not require you to put everything in a `ready` handler; it's actually better to move your code to the bottom of the page and execute it immediately.
   Unlike `document.addEventListener('load', ...)`, jQuery's `ready` event will not wait for images to load.
   Also, it works in IE, and it will still run your code even if the document already loaded.

Answer (score 27):

Well, [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is quite useful because [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) is only supported from Internet Explorer 9 onwards.

The reverse is true for e.g. the [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events: those are only supported by IE (so far), and jQuery emulates them in other browsers.

Answer (score 14):

The biggest reason for me is cross browser compatibility, especially with event handling.

Answer (score 6):

The idea behind jquery is "Write less, do more".

With trivial examples the difference in the amount of code written is small, but as you start to write more complicated stuff the power of jquery becomes apparent.

There's also a lot of cross-browser stuff built into jQuery, which means you have to worry less about browser-specific code.

Answer (score 3):

Because the jQuery developers are way smarter than I am, and will often implement a more efficient algorithm to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I have more confidence in jQuery being platform-independent than I do with mere JavaScript. For that reason, I'm tempted to use jQuery as much as I can. And I think jQuery is good and stable enough of a platform to abstract away some of the browser-specific complications that way.

Answer (score 1):

cause it's Cross-Compatible and well supported (think about XHR requests)... but in some project I'd find better to use MooTools instead of JQuery in cause of a lack of "assets" method.